# how to change arraylist to list in java

Tags: java

I'm new to java,i'm trying to names display in list format but it displaying arraylist format.

```
public List getNames(String empId) {
   List<String> empList = new ArrayList<String>();
   Session session = null;

   try{
       session =  getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().openSession();
       Query qu = session.createSQLQuery("select TITLE from EMP_NAMES_DEVISION");

       List li =  qu.list();
       for (Iterator itr = li.iterator(); itr.hasNext();) {
          Object obj = (Object) itr.next();
          String disName = (String) obj;
          EmpDetails edl = new EmpDetails();

          edl.setNames(disName);
          System.out.println("---edl---"+edl);
          empList.add(edl.toString());
          System.out.println("Nameslist--->"+ empList);
      }
   } catch(Exception e){
       e.printStackTrace();

   } finally {
       if(session!=null) {
        session.close();
     }
    }

return empList;
}
```

Output:

Nameslist--->[Akhil,reddy]

But i want display like Akhil,reddy.What is wriong in my code.

i'm not getting any errors.

Comment: What is 'list format'? What output do you expect?

Comment: @Tichodroma: i'm expecting **Akhil,reddy**

Comment: Don't you get this? What is wrong with `[Akhil,reddy]`?

Answer (score 0):

You use default implementation of toString method for list. But you want custom behavior. You can write function something like
`String mkString(List<String> result)` performing that operation and use it in println.